# How can I represent a class of existing python api in Django?

Tags: python, django, git, git-annex, datalad

I'm trying to integrate an existing python API, (it's not a web API, it's a python library called [Datalad](http://docs.datalad.org/en/stable/modref.html)) into a Django application.

Going deeper, I'd like do create a django model that represents a dataset class, that is the representation of a git/git-annex repository.

The django model class should mirror [dataset class](http://docs.datalad.org/en/stable/generated/datalad.api.Dataset.html#datalad.api.Dataset) attributes
and methods and eventually extend them.

My purpose is to create a django application to create and manage git/git-annex repositories that will become a storage backend for generic objects serialized as json (added to git tree) or binary files (managed by git-annex).

For example I'll have django models representing contents like video, audio, hypertext etc and the model representing repositories.

When I add a video I'll have the video itself added to a choosen git-annex repository with its metadata serialized and commited into git as a json file.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome, it would be nice if we had more information on what you need. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find which information to include. Are you looking to store the basic attributes of the dataset and what does the schema look like?

Comment: Thank you @cwahls! I expanded the question.. I hope you can understand better my needings :)